# Power Inequality for nonnegative number and power

Tags: inequality

I am not quite sure the following fundamental inequality:

Let $x$, $y\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a$, $b\in \mathbb{R}^+$.  Can I say $$x^a>y^a \Rightarrow x>y$$

and $$x^a>y^b \Rightarrow x>y^{b/a} \text{ ?}$$

Thanks for help.

Comment: Asking the second inequality was sufficient, because the first is just an instance of it, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the two relationship is correct  because :

$x^a>y^a$$\Rightarrow (x^{a}) {^{\frac{1}{a}}}>(y^{a}) {^{\frac{1}{a}}} $$\Rightarrow x>y$

And:

$x^a>y^b$$\Rightarrow (x^{a}) {^{\frac{1}{a}}}>(y^{b}) {^{\frac{1}{a}}} $$\Rightarrow x>y^{\frac{b} {a}} $

But that is correct if $( a, b) \in \mathbb{R^{*+}} $and$ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R^{*+}} /({1}) $

Comment: Why did you add $-1$?

Comment: Because if $x=y=1 $$\Rightarrow 1 >1 $ that isn't correct